# Random number selection from a data-frame

Tags: r, random, statistics, dataframe

I have created a dataframe of "errors" following the steps outlined by Bernaard & Sijtsma's (2000) two-way method for missing data imputation. In order to complete my calculation for missing data, I need to make a random selection of a SINGLE NUMBER from this error dataframe and add it to my already calculated missing data values.

I am familiar with the sample() function, but I am not looking for a random sample of a row or a column, but rather one individual cell from a data-frame. Is there a simple way to do this, such as a single "select random number()" command? Is there an alternative method I have yet to explore?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what your data frame looks like? Reproducible code will help attract useful answers :)

Answer (score 2):

It's easier if you can convert to a `matrix` instead of a `dataframe` , but on the assumption that you need to keep different data types or some such limitation,

```
foo<-as.data.frame(matrix(runif(20),nrow=4,ncol=5))
foo[sample(1:nrow(foo)),sample(1:ncol(foo))]
```

will pick a random element.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what @CarlWitthoft answered, you can convert your data frame back to matrix to make sure you sample a random cell

```
> set.seed(10)
> M <- data.frame(matrix(runif(20), nrow = 4, ncol = 5))
> M
#          X1         X2        X3        X4         X5
# 1 0.5074782 0.08513597 0.6158293 0.1135090 0.05190332
# 2 0.3067685 0.22543662 0.4296715 0.5959253 0.26417767
# 3 0.4269077 0.27453052 0.6516557 0.3580500 0.39879073
# 4 0.6931021 0.27230507 0.5677378 0.4288094 0.83613414

> sample(as.matrix(M), 1)  
# [1] 0.2641777            ## came from row 2, column 5
> sample(as.matrix(M), 1)  
# [1] 0.113509             ## came from row 1, column 4
> sample(as.matrix(M), 1)  
# [1] 0.4288094            ## came from row 4, column 4
> sample(as.matrix(M), 1)  
# [1] 0.2723051            ## came from row 4, column 2
```

`seq(as.matrix(M))` will show you all the cell numbers (top to bottom, left to right).  You could also sample from that.

```
> seq(as.matrix(M))
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
> sample(seq(as.matrix(M)), 1)
# [1] 15
```