# R: Sample n elements in certain columns in a dataframe/matrix and replace their values

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, sample

I am struggling to solve the captioned problem.

My dataframe is like:

```
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5

1 1  2  3  4  5

2 6  7  8  9 10

3 11 12 13 14 15
```

What I am trying to do is randomly selecting 3 elements from the third and fourth column and replace their values by 0. So the manipulated dataframe could be like

```
 X1 X2 X3 X4 X5

1 1  2  3  4  5

2 6  7  0  0 10

3 11 12 13 0 15
```

I saw from here [Random number selection from a data-frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23662502/random-number-selection-from-a-data-frame?rq=1) that it could be easier if I convert the data frame into matrix, so I tried

```
mat <- data.frame(rbind(rep(1:5, 1), rep(6:10, 1), rep(11:15, 1)))
mat_matrix <- as.matrix(mat)
mat_matrix[sample(mat_matrix[, 3:4], 3)] <- 0
```

But it just randomly picked 3 elements across all columns and rows in the matrix and turned them into 0.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with a for loop in this case. Perhaps like this:

```r
mat <- data.frame(rbind(rep(1:5, 1), rep(6:10, 1), rep(11:15, 1)))
cols <- c(3,4)

n <- nrow(mat)*length(cols)
v <- sample( x=1:n, size=3 )
m <- matrix(FALSE, ncol=length(cols), nrow=nrow(mat))
m[v] <- TRUE

for( i in seq_along(cols) ) {
    mat[ m[,i], cols[i] ] <- 0
}
```

Just create a two column "index matrix" that you sample on and use to replace back into your data.

Comment: Thank you @Sirius!  But I wanted to select 3 elements in total from column 3 and 4 instead of 3 elements in each column (so it should do the random sampling out of 8 elements). Is there a way to do that?

Comment: of course there is! but surely you mean sample from 6 elements, as 3 rows and 2 columns gives a total of 6?

Comment: Yes sorry that was a mistake: I meant 6 absolutely

Comment: Also don't easily get blinded by the neatness of tidyverse and data.table. Simple, readable code that clearly indicates intent also has value. No need to overcomplicate simple tasks.

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you so much:D And yeah you are definitely right about avoiding overcomplicating stuff

Answer (score 1):

You can use `slice.index` and `sample` from that.

```
mat_matrix[sample(slice.index(mat_matrix, 1:2)[,3:4], 3)] <- 0
```

Comment: Learned a new operation `slice.index` from you! Upvoted!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using `replace`

```
cols <- c("X3", "X4")
N <- 3
df[cols] <- replace(as.matrix(df[cols]), sample(length(unlist(df[cols])), N), 0)
```

such that

```
> df
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1  1  2  3  0  5
2  6  7  8  0 10
3 11 12  0 14 15
```

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering if I could modify your code a little bit in order to sample only the nonzero elements but failed... I tried df[cols] <- replace(as.matrix(df[cols]), sample(length(unlist(df[cols]!=0)), N), 0). Could you please help me with that?